# Add multiple Image instance into a Label

Tags: java-me

Is it possible to pass multiple Image instance such as an Image array in a single Label???If possible then how can I implement it.I want to add this Label into a screen using addComponent() method.Please give some example how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add images in string item. You can add multiple images in form or canvas and set string in front/after images.

Answer (score 0):

no you cant do so

here is example for j2me label : [label-midlet](http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/label-midlet.shtml)